# Nome dos campos da tabela em maiuscula no resultado da consulta

Tags: php, array

***Isto é só um exemplo.***

**Consulta no SQLSERVER**

SELECT doc.* FROM DOCUMENTOS doc

***esta consulta retorna um array em php***

```
$data['NUMERO'] => 12545
$data['serie'] => 1
$data['nome_emissor'] => TESTE DE EMISSOR
$data['id_destinatario'] => 190
```

**Tenho o seguinte código em PHP**

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // cria um array
    $this->vars['data'][$row['NUMERO']]['SERIE'] = $row['SERIE'];
    $this->vars['data'][$row['NUMERO']]['NOME_EMISSOR'] = $row['NOME_EMISSOR'];
    $this->vars['data'][$row['NUMERO']]['ID_DESTINATARIO'] = $row['ID_DESTINATARIO'];
}
```

*O problema é que no PHP 8.1 os nomes do campos são case sensitive, ocorre um erro no acesso do elemento do array, os campos serie, nome_emissor e id_destinatario não são acessado, pois a consulta retorna os nomes dos campos em minúsculo.
Gostaria que minha consulta retorna-se com os nomes dos campos em maiúscula ou qualquer outra solução para o problema.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode fazer um `foreach` e mudar as chaves para maiúscula.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    unset($data[$key]);
    $data[mb_strtoupper($key)] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!